# Is it possible to check whether branch creation was from Github Portal or from Android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

How to check git log whether branch Creation from Github Portal or from Local Android Studio ?.

Comment: Have you checked the first commit log entry meta data of that branch? Often in a web portal the configured user name and/or email can be slightly different.

Comment: No , how can I ?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

Comment: When you create a branch, only a new pointer to a commit is created.... so, unless the name of the branch has any meaning, there is nothing to know about where a branch was created.